# Python: How do I create a diagonal matrix with block matrices as diagonals

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

I need to create a  matrix of the form shown in the picture, this is a 9x9 matrix, but I want to create it for NxN matrix for a given value of N.

Is it possible to create this by first defining two block matrices, first of which repeats along the diagonal and the second repeats by diagonal offset of 1 and -1?

This shows the picture of the final matrix I need:

[image]

Comment: SO is not a good place to dump requirements with zero effort and expect someone to do your work for you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I assume your question is answered.

Comment: The original way of creating sparse matrices uses the `coo` style of input.  There are also several diagonal styles, and a block matrix one.

Comment: Another approach: define the subblocks: `a = np.array([[-4,1,0],[1, -4,1],[0,1,4]]); b=np.eye(3,dtype=int); c=np.zeros((3,3),int)`, and join them with the new `block` function: `M = np.block([[a,b,c], [b,a,b], [c,b,a]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a `function` that does what you want, even though you didn't attempt it yourself because I thought it was a cool problem.

---

The `function` uses `broadcasting` to assign `3x3` blocks along the `diagonals`.

```
def matrix(n):
    a = np.zeros((n,n), np.int8)
    for d in range(0, int(n/3)+4, 3):
        a[d:d+3, d:d+3] = np.array([[-4, 1, 0], [1, -4, 1], [0, 1, -4]])
    for d in range(0, int(n/3)+3, 3):
        a[d:d+3, d+3:d+6] = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
        a[d+3:d+6, d:d+3] = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
    return a
```

and a test:

```
>>> matrix(9)
array([[-4,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1, -4,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1, -4,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0, -4,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  1, -4,  1,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  1, -4,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -4,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1, -4,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1, -4]], dtype=int8)
```

---

And just to show it works, I plotted the result with `matplotlib` and got:

[image: plot]

Comment: Can you please explain the program ?

Comment: Can I do this using one of the sparse matrix function in scipy?
can you help me with this ?

Comment: @AzlaanMustafaSamad It works by looping through the diagonals and applying your pattern to that `3x3` segment of the `matrix`. If you follow the code, you should be able to see what is going on. I am not familiar with `sparse` `matrix` `functions`, so I cannot help with that, anyway you should ask a new question with this specific requirement. As for this one, please `accept` my answer (`grey` --> `green` tick next to the answer) to show that it has solved your problem. Thank you!